# WCF REST + Routing + Basic Authentication + Custom Authentication is not working

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest, basic-authentication, asp.net-routing

Diving into WCF RESTful Services and coming across the following error:

### > Server Error in '/' Application.

```
 IIS specified authentication schemes 'None', but the binding only supports
 specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication
schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous.
Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used.
```

Here is the scenario:

I am developing a WCF service that is using Routing to remove the `.svc` from the URL. So I can get to `http://mySite/MyService`. This is working perfectly when I have anonymous authentication enabled.

To accomplish this I followed [Steve Michelotti's tutorial on "RESTful WCF Services with No svc file and No config"](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/08/21/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config.aspx).

The code breaks down to the following:

My actual service class is:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation

 Namespace Service

<ServiceContract()> _
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)> _
Public Class Product

    <OperationContract()> _
    <WebInvoke(Method:="GET")> _
    Public Function GetProducts() As String
        Return "Listing ALL Products"
    End Function

End Class
```

End Namespace

Routing is enabled in the 'Global.asax' file as:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(New ServiceRoute("Product", New WebServiceHostFactory(), GetType(Service.Product)))
End Sub
```

My 'web.config' looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="OLAPIBasicAuthModule" type="Service.ServiceValidator" />
    </modules>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Data.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>        
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Now, to handle the basic authentication I followed [Mike Volodarsky's tutorial on "Developing a Module Using .NET"](http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-a-module-using-net).

This essentially gives me a class which validates the request.

When I run the debugger the browser requests the username/password from me. When I enter them it then validates through my custom validator and returns true, however, the service call then fails with the error at the top of this question.

As I said, if i enable anonymous authentication all works. I can visit `http://mySite/Product/GetProducts` and my test string is returned.

I have tried numerous entries in the web.config setting various Services/Bindings/Behaviours etc to enable Basic Auth, though they typically result in the above error.

I have a feeling it is because I am mixing technologies; I.E using routing to call my service rather than using endpoints etc..

That said, my understanding of WCF services is pretty limited at the moment.

Ultimately, I need to be able to use routing (to negate .svc in URL) and enable basic authentication, but have my own custom validator as usernames/passwords will be in SQL and not help on the server/IIS itself.

Any ideas?

Oh... I also tried this in my config.:

```
<bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="httpBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Still resulted in the same error